# What's the difference between !, %, and @ in replacement tokens?

Tags: tokens

I'm using the Message module on Drupal 7.  For **Replacement tokens**, the help text says:

> A comma-separated list of replacement tokens, e.g. %title or !url, of
>   which the message text makes use of. Each replacement token has to
>   start with one of the special characters "@", "%" or "!". This
>   character controls the sanitization method used, analogously to the
>   t() function.

What's the difference between %, !, and @?  Are there standards about when I should use each symbol?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [`format_string()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/format_string/7) docs:

- **@variable**: Escaped to HTML using [`check_plain()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7). Use this as the default choice for anything displayed on a page on the site.
- **%variable**: Escaped to HTML and formatted using [`drupal_placeholder()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_placeholder/7), which makes it display as *emphasized* text.
- **!variable**: Inserted as is, with no sanitization or formatting. Only use this for text that has already been prepared for HTML display (for example, user-supplied text that has already been run through `check_plain()` previously, or is expected to contain some limited HTML tags and has already been run through [`filter_xss()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/filter_xss/7) previously).